# Test Java RESTful calls to Web API .Net

Tags: java, c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I have a weird question. I am working on a Java project for work, where we need to make HTTP GET/POST calls to our WEB API. I wanted to make a WebAPI testing project in C#; run it locally (localhost on some random port) and make sure I am sending the right stuff. That way I could control what was sent back(success, errors, JSON, XML, and different variables like that).

Here is some key stuff I have so far:

Client-Java code:

```
public String sendAPIRequest( HttpRequestMethod method, String apiURI, String payload) throws IOException
{
    // Method is GET, POST....
    // apiURL specific API navigating to.
    // pauload is the html body.

    if(payload == null)
    {
        payload = "";
    }

    // Establish a connection.
    String strURL = String.format("%s%s", this.BaseURL, apiURI);
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", this.CHARSET);
    conn.setRequestMethod(method.toString());
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/json;charset=" + this.CHARSET);
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.connect();

    // write the payload out, if it exists.
    //if(payload != null)
    {
        try(OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream())
        {
            output.write(payload.getBytes(CHARSET));
        }
    }

    // read the response.
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();

    try(Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(input))
    {
        while(inputScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            response.append((inputScanner));
        }
    }

    return response.toString();

}

public String CheckForApplicableLicenses(String dCode, String key)
{
    String result;
    try
    {
        String APICall = String.format("/license/find_matching?d_code=%s&key=%s", dCode, key);               

        String Response = API.sendAPIRequest(HttpRequestMethod.GET, APICall);           

        // TODO Parse the String Response JSON/XMl.

        result =  Response;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: incorporate some sort of logging and error handling.
        result = ex.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Server-C#.Net code (tested with fiddler, and in the browser):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LicenseController : Controller
{

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("find_matching")]
  public IEnumerable<string> find_matching(string d_code = "", string key = "")
  {
    return new string[] { d_code, key };
  }
}
```

Results so far:
I've gotten 404 errors, and I have been able to connect. Most of the time the Java client blows up when I get to the creating the InputStream. I've never been able to trip the breakpoint in the C# server.

Questions:

1) Is what I am doing even feasible? I'm really just trying to test the Java Client, without calling the API, before I am ready. Maybe it has something to do with not running the service on the default HTTP port of 80?

2) Is there a better way of testing this? I don't want to make call to our actual service until we are done.

Thanks in advance for an assistance.

Comment: Have you thought about Fiddler? Maybe you could get away with that: you configure your Java client to use Fiddler as a proxy and you can check everything. The other way is to remove the http socket from the test: simply create a class containing the body of the request, the verb, etc, and unit test against that. I can elaborate in an answer, if you need.

Comment: I am not a java developer so I am not sure about the code but from your description it sounds like url or parameters didn't match therefore the 404 error. 
I would start by using some local $.ajax calls in your Web API project to make sure you are calling your Web API methods right then compare with you java code.
Also I find Advanced Rest Client in Chrome very useful:
https://advancedrestclient.com/